# Callaback function after success of AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using callback because i want my data to be populated on another domain (by using my javascript).

```
/*
 * 
 * Description: This function is AJAX loader for Footer and processing Callback function as a response"
 * 
 * @Param :actionName : The URL to be called           
 * 
 * */

function ajaxFooterLoader(actionName) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "http://localhost:8080/ajax/ttsGetContent.do?languageCode=en&productType=package&pageId=packageSearchResults&format=jsonp&includes=FOOTER",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            //WHAT SHOULD I DO???
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Underline , is the response I am getting after my url call through AJAX , I am passing format in url which is directly returning me my function to be called i.e. processFooter.

However , I dont understand what should I do after success , so that it directly calls my function which is been returned by callback call

**URL response from server**

```
processFooter({
    "copyRight": {
        "description": null,
        "id": null,
        "name": "&copy; 2015 AC",
        "style": null
    }
    })
```

**my function :** 
This is the function returned by AJAX and defined above AJAX call

```
/*
 * 
 * Description: This function will process footer
 * 
 * @Param :dataFooter : it takes JSON as input
 *            
 * 
 * */
function processFooter(dataFooter) {
         mergeTemplateFooter(dataFooter);
}
```

Please advice me how my ajax success should call this function?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your server seems to return JSONP, not JSON. Why?

Comment: yes , its returning JSONP for callback

Comment: even i tried with jsonp , issue is how my function will get executed after success?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your server returns JSONP, you have to tell jQuery that you are expecting JSONP:

```
dataType: 'jsonp'
```

Since the callback name seems to be hard coded, you also have to tell jQuery about it. Otherwise it will generate a random function name.

```
jsonpCallback: 'processFooter'
```

jQuery will automatically create a function with such a name, so you should change `success` to

```
 success: function(response) {
     mergeTemplateFooter(response);
 },
```

You can find for more information in the [`$.ajax` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

---

Also be aware that your `error` function will be useless here, because jQuery cannot call it if you are using JSONP:

> **error**
>
> Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests.

Comment: Is it possible jsonpCallback can have two functions. For example , if my server is returning two call back functions such as processFooter and processAboutUs ?

Comment: No, it's not possible. JSONP is well defined format, there can't be two function calls (if there is, it's not JSONP but arbitrary JavaScript).

Comment: can you give me any trick , because in my url includes are FOOTER,ABOUT_US which is returning two functions  processFooter and processAboutUs and I just want to make one call to a server

Comment: If you only want to make a single call, you'd have to pass all the data back to a single callback, i.e. `callback(allTheDataHere`). Then on the client side you need a function that pass the correct subset of data to the other two functions.

Comment: sorry , i didn't get !! can you provide me any example...Really appreciated

Comment: Your server could return `processTemplate({footer: {...}, aboutUs: { ... }});` and you would have a function that does something like `function processTempalate(data) { mergeTemplateFooter(data.footer); mergeTemplateAboutUs(data.aboutUs); }`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should be only returning the JSON object from your server:

```
{
  "copyRight": {
    "description": null,
    "id": null,
    "name": "&copy; 2015 AC",
    "style": null
  }
}
```

Secondly you can do one of two things, send directly to your named function:

```
success: processFooter,
```

or (more commonly)

```
success: function(response) {
  //WHAT SHOULD I DO???
  processFooter(response);
},
```

even better get rid of your `processfooter()` function and just use:

```
success: function(response) {
  //WHAT SHOULD I DO???
  mergeTemplateFooter(response);
},
```

best of all:

```
success: function(response) {
  //WHAT SHOULD I DO???
  //Perform your mergeTemplateFooter() code here.
},
```

Comment: `success: processFooter(response),` is incorrect. It will *call* `processFooter` immediately. It should be `success: processFooter`. Why do you claim putting everything into the `success` would be "the best"? Separation of concern is a good pattern.

Comment: In my understanding the "concern" is to get and process the footer, why should he have to make a separate call.

Comment: *"get and process the footer"* See, and I separate "getting" from "processing". This allows you to easily change how to get the data or how to process the data without affecting the other process. But everybody has a different style of structuring their app. There is nothing wrong with suggesting a different approach, if you can provide good reasons for it. But claiming that it is "the best" is just a bit over the top IMO.

Comment: Maybe the superlative was wrong, but my answer was still valid.

Out of curiosity, why is calling the processFooter directly wrong?

Comment: I never said it wasn't (except the one issue I pointed out (which is still an issue)).

Comment: Quoting myself: *"`success: processFooter(response)` is incorrect. It will call `processFooter` immediately. It should be `success: processFooter`."*

Comment: Ah hell, I should have caught that! And I didn't read your response in the right way.